# Logically, could the word "University" mean the opposite of "Diversity"?

Tags: word-usage, prefixes

> DI- twice; two-; double.
>   DI-VERSE: showing a great deal of variety; very different.
>   DI-VERS-ITY: the state of being diverse; variety.
>
> UNI- one; having or consisting of one.

While, by definition, "universe" means "the cosmos," and "university" means a college, would it be wrong to use them in a sense meaning the opposite of "diverse" or "diversity"?
i.e. The university of the establishment is quite the opposite of its diverse counterpart.

Comment: I'm afraid that niche has been taken by _universality_, although that still has a slightly different meaning. Off-topic: _it's_ is short for _it is_, _its_ is possessive.

Comment: You caught me haha I'm usually the one being anal about that. Thanks for your comment! :)

Comment: Reminds me of a joke I heard about Congress being against progress, and the Constitution against prostitution.  Ours is a weird language.

Comment: Language is not logical in the conventional sense. It is not designed. It grows organically, without oversight or governance, emerging from the minds and mouths and hands of millions and billions of people over hundreds and thousands of years. This is why any argument which seeks to impose logic on language, to treat natural language as it it were algebra, refactoring it, making substitutions, cavilling about redundacy or contradictions .. this is why any such argument ultimately founders.  Language is not algebra. We have to abandon that notion.

Comment: If "di-" was a number prefix here (and the answer points out that it is not) it is from Greek not Latin, so your proposed word should be "monoversity."

Comment: Etymologically, it won't hold. In practice, though, it can work just fine. Example: the University of Copenhagen participated in this year’s LGBT Pride Parade with a float, and their banners all had the word _University_ struck out and _Diversity_ written on them instead, [like this](http://www.kreathea.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/CopenhagenPrideParade_Designlinje2014_Produktoversigt.jpg). Worked great.

Comment: You might be looking for the word 'unity'.

Comment: But consumption is not against prosumption...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: it's still an etymologically "legitimate" play on words, in that it's the same *versus* in both words from Latin *vertere*. It's just that the di- doesn't mean what the questioner hoped, so the questioner's explanation for their version relegates it to a pun ;-)

Comment: I'll agree, but only if you concede that Congress means the opposite of Progress.

Comment: I think actually `uniformity` is the opposite of diversity?

Comment: Why not triversity? Is one the opposite of two? If a sofa comes in 2 or 3 seater, surely 3 is the opposite of 2 in that context.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that the word "university" *doesn't* mean the opposite of "diversity," your logic has a flaw: The "di-versity" comes from the Latin *di(s)vers-*, which has the same "dis" as in the Latin synonym *divertere*, namely "apart."  Both words mean "to turn away."

"Dy-," meaning two, comes from Greek. "Twice" in Latin is *bis*.

Comment: Moreover *universus*, from which *university* ultimately comes from, means *whole* and not *one* (a university is a *community*(=together, the whole) of students and teachers).

Comment: @Bakuriu Well, *uni-versus* can be understood as *one-sided* or that-which-doesn't-changed-when-turned

Comment: @Bakuriu *whole* is *as one*, *joined*, *together*. The usage of whole and one here are synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, the meaning *consisting of one* does not imply that *it is not diverse*.

Indeed, the meaning of *universe*, which is the one that everything is included in, implies that it has everything and thus it entails a huge diversity.

Answer (score 0):

The original question should be answered in the affirmative:
"Universus" literally means "turned into one"
"Diversus" literally means
"Turned different ways"

Obviously, one thing cannot be both turned into one and yet set in different directions at the same time.

As to whether the universe is diverse, if the answer is "yes" it is because the terms are not being used literally; "universe" merely referring to a large group of things (but not turning them into one thing), and "diverse" merely referring to a multitude of observed properties that things in the large group (universe) possess.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).